# Passing arguments to a Python script from bash

Tags: python, bash

Being very unfamiliar with Python, I'm trying to run the following Python script from bsPlugins :
https://github.com/bbcf/bsPlugins/blob/master/bsPlugins/FileConvert.py
I downloaded Python 2.7, the required modules (biopython, bioscripts, bbcflib, bsPlugins), and can now run in bash :

```
python FileConvert.py
```

without any error message. I am now struggling to pass arguments to the script. I see the opt variables in the source code but I'm clueless on how to feed them, or at least get information about the expected syntax.

Comment: `FileConvert.py` does not appear to take any commandline arguments, so I'm not sure why you expect it to be able to do so. You will probably have to rewrite it yourself so it can actually parse commandline arguments, using a module like `argparse`.

Comment: The script is suppose to convert a given file into a specified format. See here :http://bbcf.epfl.ch/bsplugins/_modules/bsPlugins/FileConvert.html#FileConvertPlugin

Comment: You might try asking the providers of that plugin how it is supposed to work. The documentation seems poor at best.

Comment: @Zoz I have to agree with Etan Reisner. At least as written, `FileConvert.py` is not doing anything to take arguments from the command line. That task is usually done with the `sys` module, which isn't imported anywhere in this file.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to accept command line arguments in python is by using the `sys` module as follows:

```
import sys
print str(sys.argv)
```

So when you run `python FileConvert.py arg1 arg2 arg3` in terminal, you will get the output as:

```
['FileConvert.py', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
```

Always remember that `argv` is a list of strings and `argv[0]` holds the first argument which is the `file name` and not `arg1`.

Hope this answers your question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ python FileConvert.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Although, I don't think this file accepts command line arguments either. You can rewrite it to accept arguments using `sys.argv`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

print str(sys.argv)
```